# Code completion for Javascript libraries in Brackets

Tags: javascript, adobe-brackets, code-hinting

Using Brackets, how can I have auto complete for functions defined in helpers.js file from someController.js file?

Visual Studio does this through reference paths like this:

```
/// <reference path="../libs/helpers.js" />
```

Is there any equivalent feature in Brackets?

Comment: Check this answer out on a related post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22678971/4515720

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't answers my question. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brackets does not support this currently, not even through extensions. Unfortunately, Brackets is really just a text editor, not an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for this, I'm using version 1.7 of Brackets and it has built in support for auto-completion using [Tern](http://ternjs.net/). I did have a problem where I installed an extension named ternific and it actually ended up disabling support for auto-completion. However, out of the box Brackets supports auto-completion for your own code and a number of libraries.

Comment: you say that Brackets _"supports auto-completion for your own code"_ I have defined various `data` types in my JS file in brackets editor, i.e. `Array`, `String`, etc.  however when I use dot notation for a property, say `arrayName.length`, there isn't any code auto-completion or hints listings the various methods/properties on JS objects showing in Brackets.  How are you getting auto-complete to work for your JS in brackets?

Comment: I've mostly moved over to VSCode at this point. I just fired up brackets and it's now version 1.9 and it wasn't working. I don't know if something broke or if I got it wrong before.